# How to proxypass every contexts from public domain to a virtual host domain with Apache?

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have one server and two domains,

a public domain '**apple.com**' for service,
and a private domain '**grape.com**' for internal network.

I tried to ProxyPass every contexts after `apple.com` to `grape.com`.
For example, `apple.com/pie` should be headed to `grape.com/pie`
etc.

---

My attempt)

- Apache configuration

```
# apple.com is the public domain and default servername of this server

<VirtualHost *:80>
    
    # grape.com is a private domain that only this server uses
    ServerName grape.com 
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # ProxyPass to some Tomcat+Spring project service
    # 'dir-under-webapps' has META-INF, WEB-INF, org under it.
    ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:${servicePort}/dir-under-webapps/" 
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:${servicePort}/dir-under-webapps/"
    
</VirtualHost>

<Directory ${fullpath-of-dir-under-webapps}>
    Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Location "/grape">
  ProxyPass http://grape.com/
  ProxyPassReverse http://grape.com/
</Location>
```

---

- Result

1. When I change my `hosts` file in my local pc to bind `grape.com` to the server and type `http://grape.com/` on browser, there is no problem. Everything is ok.
2. When I try to open `http://apple.com/grape` It opens up the index page, but after logging in, it pops up major 404 erros of static files.
   e.g.)
   `https://apple.com/eav/getEAVObjectValueDetailBlobInfo.json` 404 not found
   `https://apple.com/project/getProjectProgressForList.json` 404 not found
   `https://apple.com/pcommon/getListAllIndex.json` 404 not found
   `https://apple.com/libs/polyfill/promise-auto.js` 404 not found

---

- Question

It seems like my configuration drops `/grape/` context during the proxy. How do I fix this?

Comment: I'm starting to think this is tomcat version related behaviour. 
I had similar experience before.  
Current Tomcat 8.0.53 -> Planning to test with Apache Tomcat Version 8.5.41. Will update later.